# Can't enter the full IPv6 address

Tags: ip, ipv6

I have a typical home router and I want to set Cloudflare IPv6 DNS address. But the problem is I can only enter 15 characters and Cloudflare IPv6 address has 20 characters. What does this mean? Is there a way to convert 20 characters to 15 characters? I'm not familiar with IPv6 So, any help will be appreciated.

Cloudflare IPv6 addresses: `2606:4700:4700::1111` and `2606:4700:4700::1001`

[image: Screenshot of the router DNS configuration form]

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you *could* enter it, there's no guarantee that the device will be able to *store* it. Talk to the manufacturer.

Comment: The DNS is still looking for an IPv4 address. The good news is that DNS servers can server both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, even for the other protocol. You can enter an IPv4 address for a DNS server, and it can serve IPv6 AAAA records.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, it will not store the data. When I try to save the IP address (2606:4700:4700: - 15 characters), it shows an error saying 'Invalid DNS address'.  This is expected because fully completed IP address was not entered.

Comment: You've missed my point. But that's okay.

Comment: @RonMaupin, Thank you. I actually configured that (Both in Windows & Router). I just curious to know why I'm not able to enter the full IPv6 addresses. I was hoping there was a way to convert IPv6 address or something...

Comment: No. It seems to be a limitation of the device code. You could check to see if there are any updates, and certainly, you can gripe to the vendor.

Comment: @RonMaupin, There are no updates. I'll try to contact the vendor. Thank you.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Well, I can enter the IP address by changing inspect if that's what you mean. it actually stores the data in the router. But I do not know whether it's working or not. Seems to be it's not working. Thank you for reminding me that.

Comment: What everyone else seems to be avoiding saying is: It's bizarre and stupid that a router wouldn't support entering IPv6 addresses in its "IPv6 DNS Configuration" page. But that seems to be exactly what's going on here. And that's not really "typical" these days. Virtually every home router currently on sale supports IPv6 much better than that.

Comment: What model is that ? (so I can avoid buying fro that vendor)

Comment: It's a PROLiNK router. I didn't want to say the brand because I bought it from the local ISP. its firmware was modified by them. Maybe they don't support IPv6 so, they might have changed that...